# Rotman Abstract Algebra Correspondence Theorem clarification

Tags: group-theory

Hello I'm going through Rotman's First Course in Abstract Algebra and I came across a stumbling block, wondering if anyone can help me.

In Lemma 6.10, it says:

Let G be a finite p-primary abelian group,

i) If $S\subseteq G$, then $d(G/S)\leq d(G)$

ii)If $S$ is a pure subgroup of G, then d(G) = d(S) + d(G/S).

Proof: By the correspondence theorem, p(G/S) = (pG+S)/S ...

This is the part which I do not understand, how is this a manifestation of the correspondence theorem? How I interprete p(G/S) is $\{pg + S|g\in G\}$, so it makes sense for the LHS to be pG/S. But where did the +S in (pG+S)/S come from?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding some concept: Also, is p(g + S) = pg + S or pg + pS?

Comment: I had the exact same doubt when reading that proof a few weeks ago. $p(G/S)$ is a subgroup of $G/S$. The correspondence theorem says that there is a _unique_ subgroup of $G$ containing $S$ such that it maps to $p(G/S)$ under the canonical projection. Now, $pG+S$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $S$. Furthermore, $\pi (pG+S) = p(G/S)$. Then, by uniqueness, $p(G/S)=(pG+S)/S$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. Though, is (pG+S)/S = pG/S ? Since the LHS are expressions of the form pg + s + S, at the middle s should be absorbed into S by associativity of group operations.

Answer (score 0):

$pG$ is a subgroup of $G$. To talk about $pG$ modulo S (i.e. $pG/S$, as a group), first we have to ensure that $S$ is a *subgroup* of $pG$. This is not necessarily the case in general.

So if $pG$ does not contain $S$, then to factor it out by $S$, we do: first consider the *smallest* subgroup of $G$ which contains both $S$ and $pG$. It is precisely $pG+S$ (since $G$ is abelian).

Thus, $pG+S$ *contains $S$*, and then we can factor it by $S$, to get $p(G/S)$.

Here, roughly, in $(pG+S)/S$, factoring $S$ by $S$ itself gives $\{0\}$ and so we get $p(G/S)$.